# How to prevent multiple user login from the same user id in asp.net using cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

In my asp.net web application i want to prevent multiple user login from the same user name on different machine or the same pc by using Cache.So, in my Global.asax.as page,

i put this line...

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (Session["user"] != null) // e.g. this is after an initial logon
     {
        string sKey = (string)Session["user"];
        string sUser = (string)HttpContext.Current.Cache[sKey];
     }
   }
```

and in my page login submit button click,

```
string userName=uName.Text;
string passWord=pwd.Text;

string sKey = uName.Text;
string sUser = Convert.ToString(Cache[sKey]);
if (sUser == null || sUser == String.Empty)
           {
               TimeSpan SessTimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 0, HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout, 0, 0);
               HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(sKey, sKey, null, DateTime.MaxValue, SessTimeOut, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
               Session["user"] = TextBox1.Text.Trim();

               if (userName.Equals(db_userName) && passWord.Equals(db_password))
               {
                   Response.Write("Welcome " + userName);
               }
               else
               {
                   Response.Write("Invalid Login");
               }
           }
           else
           {
               Response.Write("<Marquee><h1><font color=red>ILLEGAL LOGIN ATTEMPT!!!</font></h1></marquee>");
               return;
           }
```

But when run my application, It is raising Session state is not available in this context error message on Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute event...

I dont know what is the issue here...So, please guide me to get out of this issue...

Or tell me another good approach instead of this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session state is not available during the initial request and may be null in subsequent requests. Check for null on session state object, not just the key/value.

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session!=null){
//Proceed with xyz
}
```

Side note, Your use of Response.Write here...while not invalid, is atypical. I would suggest redirection to areas.

Comment: :Thanks for your valuable suggestion.Could you please tell me about "how to check for null on session state object"?

Comment: I provided you with an example in my post.

Comment: Thanks a lot... just now i logged in and diectly closed the browser with out logout.So, next time i have tried...but it prevented me to logged in...How long the session cache for the user persist...

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTTPContext.Current.Session`

Comment: :Thanks..Just now i logged in and diectly closed the browser with out logout.So, next time i have tried...but it prevented me to logged in...How long session persist... i meant what is the value of the SessTimeOut variable...

Comment: default session timeout is 20 mins, if i recall.

Comment: Yes it is 20 mins, you can check it out in your web.config. If you dont have it already go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

use this event handler

```
 void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if(HttpContext.Current.Session!=null)
          {
              // Place your Code here 
          }
   }
```